# Why is there no '&' when assigning a string to a character array in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am taking an Intro to C class and I am wondering: why is an ampersand (&) not needed when assigning a string to a character array in C?

For instance, I learned `char name[10];  scanf("%s", name);`assigns a string to a character array. However, we've learned that input assignment to a variable looks like `scanf("%d", &intVariable);` for example.

Why is the `scanf` statement not `scanf("%s", &name);` ?

Comment: A string is already a pointer and its contents can be accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion specification `%s` in `scanf` expects an argument of type `char *`. Variable `name` is of type `char []` (an array of `char`).
In C, array names converted to pointer to its first element when passed as an argument to a function. So `name` already is converted to `char *` type when passed to `scanf` and you do not need to put `&` before it. Placing `&` before `name` will give the address of the array itself, i.e its type will be *pointer to an array of `char`* (`char (*)[]`). *Pointer to `char`* and *pointer to an array of `char`* both are different type and hence incompatible.

Comment: A comment would be appreciated giving the reason for the downvote?

Comment: While this is entirely correct it does not explain why giving the address of the array is wrong. Among other things, it's the same address, right? And in C++ we probably *would* define a template function that takes the address (or a reference) to an *array*, right? In order to avoid these pesky out-of-bound writes, right?

Comment: It does answer why. *it's the same address, right?*: yes, but that doesn't mean they have the same type. *And in C++ we probably would define a template function that takes the address (or a reference) to an array, right?*: **C is not C++**. *In order to avoid these pesky out-of-bound writes, right?*: This one is out-of-bound for this question.

Comment: Well, you don't explain *why* one pointer is better than the other, right? Hint: Your answer does not contain "because". And of course C is not C++ but even in C the [] operator knows and needs the size of its operand, so why does C not take a whole array address in scanf? (Hint: Because it is not part of the core language but a library function and most likely was originally not an intrinsic and because the language's type system was not designed to handle that, hence the C++ comparison) etc. Simply stating "will give the address of the array itself" does not explain why that would be wrong.